# Trying to do linear Linear Regression classifier giving me "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python

I have gon through scikit-learn toturiol using linear rgression. When I try to write my own code to do it I get a error saying
" "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
"# Use only one feature:"
the saemple code is sending a 1d array
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]

This is what I tried:
1. used  list instead of a numpy array
2. printed out diabetes_X in sample code got
[[ 0.06169621]
 [-0.05147406] ..... ]]
I then tried to change my code as follows
xp=[ [3449 ] [1058] [ 2201]] 
got a error saying end of statement expected.
I then tried
xp=[ [3449 ], [1058], [ 2201]]
same error message

My code

```
xs=np.array([ 3449 ,  1058,  2201,  2500,  1953,  1637,  1400,  1836,  1400,  4677,  1639,  2094,  1491], dtype=np.float64)
ys=np.array([529000,279090,479000,319000,369000,346000,425000,380000,425000,646900,349900,384900,284900], dtype=np.float64)

xp=[ 3449 ,  1058,  2201,  2500,  1953,  1637,  1400,  1836,  1400,  4677,  1639,  2094,  1491]
yp=[529000,279090,479000,319000,369000,346000,425000,380000,425000,646900,349900,384900,284900]

clf= linear_model.LinearRegression()

clf.fit(xp, yp)
g=clf.predict( 279090)
print("+++++++ guess +++++++")
print(g)
print("jjjjjjj")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the error states, the fit function expects a 2D array, if you have a single feature, which means you have a 1D array, you can make it 2D by using `reshape(1, -1)`
.

here is a working example:

```
xs=np.array([ 3449 ,  1058,  2201,  2500,  1953,  1637,  1400,  1836,  1400,  4677,  1639,  2094,  1491], dtype=np.float64)
ys=np.array([529000,279090,479000,319000,369000,346000,425000,380000,425000,646900,349900,384900,284900], dtype=np.float64)

xp=[ 3449 ,  1058,  2201,  2500,  1953,  1637,  1400,  1836,  1400,  4677,  1639,  2094,  1491]
yp=[529000,279090,479000,319000,369000,346000,425000,380000,425000,646900,349900,384900,284900]

xp = np.array(xp).reshape(1, -1)
yp = np.array(yp).reshape(1, -1)
clf= linear_model.LinearRegression()

clf.fit(xp, yp)
g=clf.predict(xs.reshape(1, -1))
print("+++++++ guess +++++++")
print(g)
print("jjjjjjj")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape it to a 2d array with a single column after converting them to NumPy arrays using `xp = np.array([....])` and `yp = np.array([....])`

```
xp = xp.reshape(xp.shape[0],-1)
yp = yp.reshape(yp.shape[0],-1)

clf= linear_model.LinearRegression()

clf.fit(xp, yp)
g=clf.predict( 279090)
print("+++++++ guess +++++++")
print(g)
print("jjjjjjj")

# +++++++ guess +++++++
# [[24426732.22]]
# jjjjjjj
```